# Flutter: Sending long sms with SMS_Maintained Package

Tags: flutter, dart, sms, message, smsmanager

In my project, I'm using [sms_maitained](https://pub.dev/packages/sms_maintained) version `0.2.5` and I'm trying to send message of about 230 characters. But I'm getting `RESULT_ERROR_GENERIC_FAILURE`.

I've already gone through a lot of resources like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39932647/smsmanager-returns-result-error-generic-failure-despite-trying-everything) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12987909/whats-meant-by-result-errors-of-smsmanager/12988143). I'm pretty sure:

1. there isn't any network issue
2. have proper permissions
3. no dual sim issue
4. receiver number is correct

**Because**, I am able to send messages; if the message length is shorter.

I found this java code, which divides and send longer message but I'm not good in java, and my project is in flutter so I'll prefer to do it natively on flutter. Also if I do it manually for `android` then I've to fix it for `iOS` separately.

```
ArrayList<String> texts = smsManager.divideMessage(text);
smsManager.sendMultipartTextMessage(phone, null, texts, null, null)
```

Please tell me, if there is any solution available!

Comment: I have the same problem, apparently sending multipart messages isn't implemented yet!

Comment: any solutions ???

Answer (score 0):

This solved issue with sending long SMS messages.

In your pubspec.yaml put this:

```
  sms_maintained:
    git:
      url: https://github.com/andreimc/flutter_sms.git
```

I found it here: https://github.com/geordyvcErasmus/flutter_sms/pull/15

Comment: This package is stopped now and changed with flutter_sms. So, how to send long sms in flutter_sms